# Full-screen Overlay

Tags: java, javafx, overlay

Currently, I am trying to create a timer that displays in the corner of your screen. I want it to show *even if* there is currently a full-screened application running. Currently I've tried `Stage#setAlwaysOnTop(true)`, however that only functions for normal applications, not when they are full-screened.

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        stage.setTitle("Timer");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This is the standard JavaFX example with IntelliJ, however with the one modification which was `Stage#setAlwaysOnTop(true)`. How would I get this to function ontop of the full-screen, or at least stay omnipresent no matter the application.

Comment: When I do this it stays on top of full-screen apps as expected (though not apps in full screen exclusive mode, again as expected.) If you're trying to get it to stay on top *constantly*, then you can't really achieve that with JavaFX.

Comment: This kind of control is done at OS level. The best chance you can get this to work is to play with JNA API. By default, most OS will let the latest process which requests to be top-most to be the application to be "truly" topmost. You can call `setAlwaysOnTop(false)` and `setAlwaysOnTop(true)` whenever your application cease to be "truly" topmost, but I don't think there is any way to detect this in code without JNA.